# Create a dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, dynamic

### I have made a stored procedure like this..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_dataPull] @serverName nvarchar(30), @dbName nvarchar (30), @serverName2 nvarchar(30), @dbName2 nvarchar (30)

    INSERT INTO sampleDatabase.dbo.WorkFlowCopy
      ([ServerName]
      ,[DBName]
      ,[ID]
      ,[ActivityDefinitionID]
      ,[ParentID]
      ,[Caption]
      ,[Description]
      ,[ShortDescription]

(SELECT @serverName, @dbName, sdb1.* from OPENDATASOURCE('SQLOLEDB',
'Data Source=phmnldb16\eaudit;user id=XXXX;password=XXXX').AUDIT_FSA_170_001.AUD170.Workflow sdb1)

UNION ALL

(SELECT @serverName2, @dbName2, sdb2.* from OPENDATASOURCE('SQLOLEDB',
'Data Source=phmnldb16\eaudit;user id=XXXX;password=XXXX').AUDIT_FSA_170_002.AUD170.Workflow sdb2)
```

---

This query's function is to move the the data from another server into specific table. Now, notice that I have 2 SELECT statements below and I have 4 parameters. It's because I combined 2 tables and moved it into another table.

The problem with this query is the fact that it is static. What If I need to combine 3 or more tables? Then I have to create another (SELECT and UNION ALL statement below and add another 2 or more parameters).. I want to make it DYNAMIC.

Comment: Your syntax looks like SQL Server.  Why is the question tagged Oracle?

Comment: Hello Gordon, it is SQL Server. But I tagged 5 different names as stack overflow requires.

Comment: It does not require you to tag 5

Comment: Use a cursor to cycle through a list of server and DB names. You can pass in a table parameter or a comma delineated list and use a split string function to place it in a table.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_DATAPULL @SERVER NVARCHAR(30),@DB NVARCHAR(30)
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @SERVER NVARCHAR(MAX)='SERVER1,SERVER2,SERVER3,SERVER4,SERVER5'
DECLARE @DB NVARCHAR(MAX)='DB1,DB2,DB3,DB4,DB5'
DECLARE @SRV NVARCHAR(MAX),@DBN NVARCHAR(MAX),@QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE(SERVERNAME VARCHAR(100),DB VARCHAR(100))

WHILE(SELECT CHARINDEX(',',@SERVER))>0
BEGIN
SET @SRV=(SELECT SUBSTRING(@SERVER,0,CHARINDEX(',',@SERVER)))
SET @SERVER=SUBSTRING(@SERVER,LEN(@SRV)+2,LEN(@SERVER))

SET @DBN=(SELECT SUBSTRING(@DB,0,CHARINDEX(',',@DB)))
SET @DB=SUBSTRING(@DB,LEN(@DBN)+2,LEN(@DB))
INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES (@SRV,@DBN )
END
INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES (@SERVER,@DB )

SET @QUERY=' INSERT INTO sampleDatabase.dbo.WorkFlowCopy
      ([ServerName]
      ,[DBName]
      ,[ID]
      ,[ActivityDefinitionID]
      ,[ParentID]
      ,[Caption]
      ,[Description]
      ,[ShortDescription] '

DECLARE C CURSOR FOR
SELECT SERVERNAME,DB FROM @TEMP
OPEN C
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @SERVER,@DB
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN

SET @QUERY=@QUERY+'(SELECT '''+@SERVER+''', '''+@DB+''', sdb1.* from OPENDATASOURCE(''SQLOLEDB'',
''Data Source=phmnldb16\eaudit;user id=XXXX;password=XXXX'').AUDIT_FSA_170_001.AUD170.Workflow sdb1) '

FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @SERVER,@DB
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C
SET @QUERY=SUBSTRING(@QUERY,0,LEN(@QUERY)-LEN('UNION ALL'))
PRINT @QUERY
EXEC(@QUERY)
END
```